# Issue with 2 Routes - React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I got an issue in my routes, I have a router for auth,

```
export const AuthRoute = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
        <Route path="signIn" element={<SignInPage />} />
        <Route path="signUp" element={<SignUpPage />} />

        <Route path='/*' element={<Navigate to="/auth/signIn" />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

and these are for my dashboard,

```
export const DashboardRoute = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="history" element={<HistoryPage />} />
        <Route path="contact" element={<ContactPage />} />

        <Route path='/*' element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

If the user is not authenticated, then that perticular user only has access to the login page, but If the user is authenticated then he will be having access to all the pages in the dashboard. My principal router is,

```
export const AppRouter = () => {
  ...
  ...
  if (status === authStatusConst.CHECKING) {
    return (
      <h3>Loading...</h3>
    )
  }    
  return (
    <Routes>
      {
          (status === authStatusConst.UNAUTHENTICATED)
            ? (
                <>
                  <Route path="/auth/*" element={ <SignInPage /> } />
                  <Route path="/*" element={ <Navigate to="/auth/signIn" /> } />
                </>
            )
            : (
                <>
                  <Route path="/" element={ <HomePage /> } />
                  <Route path="/*" element={ <Navigate to="/" /> } />
                </>
            )
        }
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

The issue is, If I want an access to the history page or contact page I can't do it, Only I can access the home page (I'm authenticated). I appreciate any suggestion.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

When you use "/*" that means whatever you write after "/", like "contact", it always goes to that element which you defined in that case, it is the HomePage Component. You can try with the below code.

```
<Route path='*' element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are basically trying to implement route protection. The common pattern is to create layout routes that handle the authentication status check and redirect or render an `Outlet` accordingly. Don't conditionally render the routes, instead, conditionally allow access to protected content.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  ...

  if (status === authStatusConst.CHECKING) {
    return <h3>Loading...</h3>;
  }

  return status === authStatusConst.UNAUTHENTICATED
    ? <Navigate to="/auth/signIn" replace />
    : <Outlet />;
};

const AnonymousRoutes = () => {
  ...

  if (status === authStatusConst.CHECKING) {
    return <h3>Loading...</h3>;
  }

  return status === authStatusConst.UNAUTHENTICATED
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};
```

...

```
export const AppRouter = () => {
  ...
  
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<AnonymousRoutes />}>
        <Route path="signIn" element={<SignInPage />} />
        <Route path="signUp" element={<SignUpPage />} />
      </Route>
      <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="history" element={<HistoryPage />} />
        <Route path="contact" element={<ContactPage />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace /> } />
    </Routes>
  )
};
```

If you *don't* want to render all your routes and nested routes in `AppRouter` and instead want to render components rendering descendent routes (*i.e. rendered in descendent `Routes` components*), then the parent routes need to append the `"*"` wildcard matcher to their paths so descendent routes can also be matched.

Example:

```
export const AuthRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/signIn" element={<SignInPage />} />
        <Route path="/signUp" element={<SignUpPage />} />
        <Route path='/*' element={<Navigate to="/auth/signIn" />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export const DashboardRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
        <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/history" element={<HistoryPage />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactPage />} />
        <Route path='/*' element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

...

```
export const AppRouter = () => {
  ...
  
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<AnonymousRoutes />}>
        <Route path="/auth/*" element={<AuthRoutes />} />
      </Route>
      <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
        <Route path="/*" element={<DashboardRoutes />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  )
};
```